# iOS 8 when Accessibility Options in opened applicationWillResignActive is not called

Tags: ios8

In iOS 7 when the user triple clicks the home button and the Accessibility Options window pops up applicationWillResignActive is called enabling us to pause the game. In iOS 8 however, applicationWillResignActive is not being called when this happens, so the game continues running in the background. As far as I can tell any other time that applicationWillResignActive would have been called in iOS 7 is still working in iOS 8.

Does anyone know if this is an intended design decision on Apple's part, or if something changed that I need to update or fix for this to work in iOS 8?